# Ensure "www" always contained in links generated by MVC built-in helpers for canonicity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, canonical-link

Using C# MVC .NET 4.5 with my `RouteConfig.cs` set to append trailing slashes and convert URLs to lower case:

```
routes.AppendTrailingSlash = true;
routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
```

I have the following canonical `link` tag in the HTML of my views:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="@Url.Action("Index", Html.GetTitleType(Model.TitleType), new { i = Model.Title.Title_Id }, Request.Url.Scheme)" />
```

This works great but needs some modification. My preferred canonical URL structure is `"http://www.example.com/something/1234/"` - If I'm however browsing the site at `"http://example.com"` then the canonical link rendered is `"http://example.com/something/1234/"` which totally defeats the purpose. How can I ensure the canonical tag contains `"http://www"` no matter what? I could obviously hardcode the URL structure myself, but would prefer a more elegant solution.

**Update**: the best I could come up with is this:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="@string.Format("{0}{1}", "http://www.example.com", @Url.Action("Index", Html.GetTitleType(Model.TitleType), new { i = Model.Title.Title_Id }))" />
```

`"http://www.example.com"` could also be stored as a key-value pair in `web.config` so that the final result looks like this:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="@string.Format("{0}{1}", @System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["canonical_root_URL"], @Url.Action("Index", Html.GetTitleType(Model.TitleType), new { i = Model.Title.Title_Id }))" />
```

Comment: Isn't that just a redirect to www you should config in your webserver?

Comment: @PatrickHofman sure, it's possible with an `HTTP 301` but not a possibility in my use case

Comment: If you are using IIS to deploy your application you can easily ensure that by modifying the binding in your site

Comment: @oussama_gd care to elaborate further?

Comment: Why do you need to support both www and non-www? It messes up your cookies, origins, etc. A redirect as @PatrickHofman suggested is much better.

Comment: @JeowLiHuan agreed that PatrickHofman's is the proper way to do this but it does not answer the question about canonical links being consistent across both www and non-www (assuming that redirects are not a possibility)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your provided answer:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="@string.Format("{0}{1}", @System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["canonical_root_URL"], @Url.Action("Index", Html.GetTitleType(Model.TitleType), new { i = Model.Title.Title_Id }))" />
```

...will work fine as it will match scenarios such as `http://example.com/something/1234`, `www.example.com/something/1234`, `http://example.com/something/1234?randomVar=5` and so on to `http://www.example.com/something/1234/`.

However, this is a good example of solving a problem that creates other problems. Patrick Hofman's and Jeow Li Huan's comments are correct — you have your canonicity issue figured out but now you have to deal with `example.com` and `www.example.com` generating their own set of cookies etc. As such, pick one scheme and stick to it by doing a permanent URL redirection  ([`HTTP 301`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)) on URLs matching the other scheme. You will then be able to use your original code:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="@Url.Action("Index", Html.GetTitleType(Model.TitleType), new { i = Model.Title.Title_Id }, Request.Url.Scheme)" />
```

...with no issues, as `Request.Url.Scheme` will always be the same due to the `HTTP 301` you enforced on the other scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Select your site in IIS manager then click on binding, add a binding with the host name example.com (without www).